# Изменения отсчёта координат RectTransfrom

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я добавляю кодом n-е количество (возможно рандомное) префабов в gameObject и столкнулся с проблемой неясности работы RectTransform.

Первое - хотелось бы, чтобы точка отсчёта координат находилась в левом верхнем углу.
Второе - нужно чтоб размеры RectTransform подстраивались под границы содержимого. (Автоматически или вручную). (Я не  хотел бы использовать Vertical Layout Group и т.п.)

Возможно у меня эта проблема возникает в следствии непонимания принципов правильного позиционирования в Unity. В частности, мне не ясно как можно позиционировать произвольное количество элементов с учётом отрицательных координат, ведь RectTransform равномерно расширяется в обе стороны от центра.
К примеру, если бы центр координат располагался-бы в углу, то можно было бы легко рассчитывать координаты любого элемента

[image: RectTransform]

Я не хотел бы добавлять лишние компоненты к родителю/детям, т.к. нацелен разобраться в принципах работы.

Код, который осуществляется добавление элементов:

```
private void drawCeils() {
    GameObject ceilGameObject;
    RectTransform ceilRectTransform;
    ColorViewerCeil ceilScript;


    float hueStep = (HueB - HueA) / (Count - 1 == 0 ? 1 : Count - 1);
    float hue = HueA;
    float spaceY = 5f;
    float ceilY = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
        ceilGameObject = Instantiate(Ceil, transform, false) as GameObject;
        ceilRectTransform = ceilGameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        ceilRectTransform.localPosition = new Vector3(ceilRectTransform.rect.xMax, ceilY + ceilRectTransform.rect.yMin, 0);
        ceilY = ceilRectTransform.localPosition.y - (ceilRectTransform.rect.size.y + spaceY);

        ceilScript = (ceilGameObject.GetComponent<MonoBehaviour>() as ColorViewerCeil);
        ceilScript.Color = Random.ColorHSV(hue, hue, 1, 1, 1, 1);
        hue += hueStep;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Точка начала координат может находиться там, где вы её расположите. Замечали на родителе такие треугольники?

[image: Якоря]

Это якоря. В данном случае - якоря выделенной кнопки (вернее, её RectTransform). Как видите, я перетащил их в левый верхний угол, и теперь свойство anchoredPosition обозначает положение кнопки относительно левого верхнего угла объекта Canvas (который, как правило, соответствует левому верхнему углу экрана. Хотя и не обязательно. Но по умолчанию - соответствует).

Так же у RT есть свойство Pivot - точка, которая отвечает за положение самого трансформа. То умолчанию она находится в центре трансофрма, соотвественно, координаты кнопки - это координаты её центра. Её так же можно сместить, например, в левый верхний угол RT (возможно, это вы и имели в виду?).

Давайте в коде переместим pivot в левый верхний угол, а затем переместим кнопку в левый верхний угол экрана (а якоря у нас уже там, хотя и ими тоже можно рулить из кода, конечно):

```
var rt = GameObject.Find("Button").GetComponent<RectTransform>();
rt.pivot = new Vector2(0, 1);
rt.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0, 0);
```

Обратите внимание: координата Y у pivot равна 1 (т.е. 100%), поскольку 0 в Unity UI - это нижняя кромка.

---

...но это не самое интересное, что можно сделать с якорями. Вот смотрите:

[image: якоряГИФ]

Как видите, не только позицию кнопки, но и её масштаб можно регулировать при помощи якорей - причём в случае, изображённом на гифке (которую я попёр [отсюда](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/UIBasicLayout.html)) масштаб определяется автоматически и завист от ширины канваса. Сходите по ссылке, там есть ещё гифки.

И ещё посмотрите [справочник](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.html)

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. Весьма исчерпывающе.

Comment: На самом деле, не исчерпывающе :) Но сориентироваться, надеюсь, помог

Comment: @Heterotroph кстати, если ответ помог вам, отметьте его как верный, пожалуйста

Comment: Да, действительно.
Вот только хотелось бы уточнить - почему в интерфейсе "уголки" для изменения anchoredPosition появляются при выделении ребёнка? А елси я хочу это сделать без него?

Comment: Так это якоря ребёнка. А сделать без него - что?

Comment: Так... ладно. У меня по всей видимости опять какое-то фундаментальное непонимание.

Comment: UPD: А нет... походу понимание всё-таки правильно, но почему-то не отображается возможность управления якорем через интерфейс, не прибегая к числовым значениям в Inspector.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, в чём проблема. Якоря отлично тягаются мышью: хватаете за треугольник, тянете куда вам надо. Перед этим нужно выделить требуемый компонент, конечно

Comment: Делаю CreateEmpty, выделяю, добавляю RectTransform.
В итоге у меня не появляются треугольники, но в параметрах RectTransform, в Anshors можно указать Min/Max. Это работает, но мне просто не ясно, почему не выводятся треугольники для якоря имненно в данном случае. (Всё выглядит так, как на скрине в моём вопросе, но только без детей)

Comment: RectTransform - это трансформ UI элемента, объект, который его содержит, должен располагаться на Canvas. Белая рамка на скриншоте и гифке - это канвас