# Аналог layout_weight из Android в UI Unity

Tags: unity3d, android-layout, unity3d-ui

В разработке приложений под Android есть замечательное свойство элемента layout как layout_weight. Оно задает такое поведение элементов layout, чтоб они занимали указанное количество пространства от родителя в процентах (грубо говоря). То есть, если есть 2 элемента и нужно, чтобы первый эл. занимал три четверти пространства родителя, а второй эл. одну четверть, то нужно установить значения layout_weight 3 и 1 соответственно.

Есть ли аналог этого свойства в UI Unity?
Как реализовать такое поведение стандартными средствами.

Comment: Неа, нету. UI кстати является OpenSource, можете сами дописать, что надо

Comment: В Unity UI это делается при помощи якорей (anchors), обычно без кода. [Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/588332/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82-recttransfrom/588453#588453), например, я про якоря немного писал